# How to remove the share icons in joomla articles

Tags: joomla

i got the follow share icons in my articles, whereas I cant explaint where they come from. I set all article-parameters to hide, and also checked the template-settings-section. The appear directly below the article content. Any ideas?

[image]
Thanks, best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places this could be hidden. There is an easy way to narrow down the possibilities. Go to any URL that has this on it and add `&tmpl=component` to the URL. This will display just the content without any of the modules on the page. If you still see it there, then you know it is not in a module position but in the component area itself.

If it is still there:

1. Look in JOOMLA/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/HTML/com_content/article/default.php, it's been hard coded in to the template override
2. As others have mentioned, it may be a plugin

If it is gone:

1. Check your modules, it's in one of those

If you still can't find it, try switching to another template. If it is still there when you switch templates, then you need to go check the core Joomla files. Look in

`JOOMLA/components/com_content/article/tmpl/default.php`.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a plugin, you can disable these in the plugin manager.

Comment: Actually I disabled all of them - no changes.

Answer (score 0):

It must be the content plugin... Please check for any active content plugins once again..

The brutal way is to remove or comment the following line from /components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php file:

```
<?php echo $this->article->event->afterDisplayContent; ?>
```

But this will disable output after article text to all content plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like AceSEF Social Bookmarks, check Components--> AceSef --> Social Bookmarks tab --> Set the option "Enable" = No.

Hope this help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be nice if you improved your answer by a reference and/or a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Every template builders use different div names for the social sharing module.

Use inspect element to find out the div name (or names).

Go to : yourtemplate/css/template.css

add 
.yourdivname {display:none;}

add this line for any additional div names.
In my case I had to add these lines and it worked.
.bt-social-share {display:none;}
.bt-social-share-below {display:none;}

OR go to your plugin manager, type in search "Social". 
Disable the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Into Joomshaper Helix 3 or Helix 3 Ultimate, to remove or add some more, go to...
BLOG...DETAILS...and deactivate SOCIAL ICONS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).